How to connect a Teltonika RUT200 router to a Google Nest Pro router to give devices connected to it internet access?
I'm currently facing an issue with setting up my home network to provide internet access to devices connected via a Teltonika RUT200 router. My goal is to maintain two separate networks in my home: one served by a Google Nest Pro WiFi router and the other by the Teltonika RUT200. Despite the separation, I want devices connected to the Teltonika network to have internet access. Here are the details of my setup and what I have attempted so far:
Current Setup:

Primary Router: Google Nest Pro WiFi, connected directly to the ISP
modem and functioning correctly with internet access.
Secondary Router: Teltonika RUT200, intended to create a separate network for
specific devices but also needs internet access.
Connection Attempt: I have tried connecting the Teltonika router’s WAN port to one of the LAN ports on the Google Nest Pro,
aiming for a setup where the Teltonika network is separate but has
internet access. DHCP is enabled on both routers, with the Google
Nest Pro handling the primary network and the Teltonika supposed to
manage its network.
Issue: Devices connected to the Teltonika network are not able to access the internet. They can connect to the Teltonika router, obtain IP addresses and communicate between each other but lack internet connectivity.

Steps Taken:

Checked WAN Settings on Teltonika: Ensured the WAN interface is set to DHCP to receive an IP address from the Google Nest Pro.
Restarted Both Routers: After making configuration changes, I restarted both routers to ensure the settings were applied.

Questions:

Are there specific settings on the Teltonika RUT200 that I need to
adjust to enable internet connectivity through the Google Nest Pro
router?
Is there an alternative method to connect these routers to achieve my
goal of separate networks with internet access on both?

Any insights, advice, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping to resolve this issue without compromising the separate networks setup I'm aiming for. Thank you in advance for your help!

Does the Teltonika router perform NAT? Normally that would be the default for a "WAN" interface, but you should check. (NAT in the middle of the network isn't great, but I don't think Nest allows any routing configuration so it's the only remaining alternative.)

I've just found information that suggests NAT is performed. See https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/RUT200_Firewall#Routing.2FNAT_Offloading. Is this something I can turn on or off to help enable internet access?

Yes, that's why I was asking whether it currently does that (specifically SNAT) or not. Did it come with any SNAT rules preconfigured, like in that article?
